# suppress console output in r markdown, but keep plot

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio

Hi I have the following markdown chunk:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE}
lapply(obj,function(x) plot(x,main="some plot") box() axis(1,at=seq(0,25,by=1))
```
````

The output is multiple plots. However I also get the console message in the pdf document underneath the plots.

```
<Plot 1> nice plot 1!
<Plot 2> nice plot 2!

-- nasty horrible console output
## [[1]] 
01.2882829 

## [[2]]
120.29393933
```

I have tried echo/warning/error/message = FALSE, but neither of these suppress the console output

please help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Wrapping any object in `invisible` will prevent automatically `print`ing it.

You should be able to use

```
invisible(lapply(obj,function(x) plot(x,main="some plot")))
```

However the fact that `echo=FALSE` doesn't work suggests that there might be something else going on.

Comment: To add some info, this is the **only** option that worked for me too.  **Any** combination of `echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='hide'` (including all of them together) did **not** work for me.

Answer (score 60):

try this:

```
{r, echo=FALSE,results='hide',fig.keep='all'}
lapply(obj,function(x) plot(x,main="some plot") box() axis(1,at=seq(0,25,by=1))
```

Comment: this works perfect for plot_model figures (for lmer objects) in rmarkdown/quarto

Answer (score 20):

These are the options that worked for me:

```
echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='hide'
```

Comment: Simply `message=FALSE` was enough for me.

Answer (score 11):

I was having this problem as well in my R notebook and `echo=FALSE` didn't do anything.  However `message=FALSE` does.

````
```{r, message=FALSE}
````

Answer (score 10):

Having `results = 'hide'` or  `results = FALSE` in your chunk options suppresses R text ***output*** but not warnings, messages or errors. No extra functions are needed.

More details can be found here.
https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#text-output

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

It will hide the errors, warning, code, and console output. It will show only the graphs.

```
{r, echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE, results='hide',fig.keep='all'}
lapply(obj,function(x) plot(x,main="some plot") box() axis(1,at=seq(0,25,by=1))
```

Later you can export it to HTML which will be neat and readable