# How to render a gganimate graph in html using rmarkdown::render(), without generating unwanted output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, gganimate

I am trying to render gganimate() plots in html using an r-markdown document. I am able to create the html document (though the simple example below takes at least a minute) and the gganimate graphic successfully loads in the browser (firefox), however, I get a bunch of unwanted output in the browser.

The unwanted output looks like this:

---

Frame 1 (1%)

Frame 2 (2%)

Frame 3 (3%)

...

Frame 96 (96%)

Frame 97 (97%)

Frame 98 (98%)

Frame 99 (99%)

Frame 100 (100%)

Finalizing encoding... done!

---

Like I said, after this unwanted output, the animation is indeed displayed correctly.

I have tried messing around with the knitR code-chunk heading options. Mostly been looking at these options here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-code.html

I have also tried the solutions suggested on this post: [suppress console output in r markdown, but keep plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810476/suppress-console-output-in-r-markdown-but-keep-plot) Specifically, I have tried wrapping the ggplot object in "invisible".

Just copy the code below into an Rmarkdown document, save this Rmarkdown document as "example.Rmd", then, in the R console run: `rmarkdown::render("example.Rmd")`

````
---
    title: "Testing gganimate with R Markdown"
    output: html_document
---

```{r message = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  # Here comes the gganimate code
  transition_states(
    gear,
    transition_length = 2,
    state_length = 1
  ) +
  enter_fade() + 
  exit_shrink() +
  ease_aes('sine-in-out')
```
````

Comment: I am not able to duplicate when knitting from a rmd file in RStudio. It works as desired.

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe it has to do with some global knit r options on my machine....or maybe I have to update some packages.....

Comment: Just updated all my packages, definitely not that

Comment: I will add my code and output to as an answer so you can compare.

Comment: So it works when I use the knitr button :), which I'm just going to do from now on. But yeah when you use rmarkdown::render(), you get the unwanted output

Comment: @IanWesley can you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One workaround for this is to assign the animation to an object `goo <- ggplot(...` and write the animation to a file `anim_save("goo.gif", goo)` while suppressing results from the code chunk `results = FALSE`. Then render the gif in markdown immediately after the code chunk `![](goo.gif)`.

E.g.

````
---
title: "Testing gganimate with R Markdown"
output: html_document
---


```{r message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, results = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
goo <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  # Here comes the gganimate code
  transition_states(
    gear,
    transition_length = 2,
    state_length = 1
  ) +
  enter_fade() + 
  exit_shrink() +
  ease_aes('sine-in-out')

anim_save("goo.gif", goo)
```


![](goo.gif)
````

Comment: Clever solution, is there an efficient way to render the gganimate plot to an html which also includes the media control  panel (play, pause, download)?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue as well, so I decided to dive into the code to see if I could get rid of the messages altogether.

It turns out that the output comes from the *gifski* package that is used by default to generate the animation. gifski lets you control whether it outputs these messages with a progress flag. *gganimate* uses the output of the `interactive()` call to set this flag.

I'm not sure why none of the chunk options in rmarkdown suppress the messages (possibly it's because they are created in *C* code) but my workaround for this issue is instead of using the interactive *R* session connected to my editor to create the document, I use the following command to create the final version of my document from the command-line:

> `R -e "rmarkdown::render('document.Rmd',output_file='document.html')"`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The example in the question now fails on my desktop (gifski 1.4.3-1, gganimate 1.0.7), though it still works on my laptop (gifski 1.4.3, gganimate 1.0.7). The desktop error is

```
File test_gganimate_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-1-1.gif not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99
Execution halted
```

I tried downgrading with `versions::install.versions("gifski", "1.4.3")`, but the error remains. Sorry I don't have time to recreate my exact other package versions at the moment.

---

ORIGINAL:

This problem seems to be gone as of late 2020, using gifski 0.8.6, gganimate 1.0.7. Here my `devtools::session_info()` after knitting the example in the question:

```
devtools::session_info()
## - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
##  setting  value                       
##  version  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
##  os       Windows 10 x64              
##  system   x86_64, mingw32             
##  ui       RTerm                       
##  language (EN)                        
##  collate  English_United States.1252  
##  ctype    English_United States.1252  
##  tz       Europe/Berlin               
##  date     2020-12-02                  
## 
## - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
##  package     * version date       lib source        
##  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  callr         3.5.1   2020-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  cli           2.2.0   2020-11-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  colorspace    2.0-0   2020-11-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  devtools      2.3.2   2020-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  digest        0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  dplyr         1.0.2   2020-08-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  farver        2.0.3   2020-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  generics      0.1.0   2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  gganimate   * 1.0.7   2020-10-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  ggplot2     * 3.3.2   2020-06-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  gifski        0.8.6   2018-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  hms           0.5.3   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  knitr         1.30    2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  labeling      0.4.2   2020-10-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  lifecycle     0.2.0   2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  magrittr      2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  pillar        1.4.7   2020-11-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  pkgbuild      1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  plyr          1.8.6   2020-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  processx      3.4.4   2020-09-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  progress      1.2.2   2019-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  ps            1.4.0   2020-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  purrr         0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  R6            2.5.0   2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  Rcpp          1.0.5   2020-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  rlang         0.4.9   2020-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  rmarkdown     2.5     2020-10-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  rprojroot     2.0.2   2020-11-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  scales        1.1.1   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  stringi       1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
##  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  testthat      3.0.0   2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  tibble        3.0.4   2020-10-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  tidyselect    1.1.0   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  tweenr        1.0.1   2018-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
##  usethis       1.6.3   2020-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  vctrs         0.3.5   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  withr         2.3.0   2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  xfun          0.19    2020-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
##  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
## 
## [1] C:/R-library
## [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library
```

Comment: Did you get it to render directly in the Rmd chunk? If yes, could you please post the code that worked (including chunk options)? Thanks!

Comment: @rmf See edit. The code I use is exactly the one in the question text.