# Serious problem with Rmarkdown transformation

Tags: r, neural-network, r-markdown

I have a problem with a rMarkdown transformation.

Basically, I have to report the results of a Neural Net.

After the transformation in a pdf file the document is full of Neural net's calculations.

I have included this chunk

---

title: "Monitoring hydraulic systems"

output: pdf_document

---

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

nNGrid=expand.grid(size=seq(1,9,1),decay=seq(0.1,1,0.1))


neuralNetwork= train(Class ~.,data=training_norm, method="nnet",
                     trControl=reg_Control,tuneGrid=nNGrid)


nNPredictions = predict(neuralNetwork,newdata=testing_norm)

ty<- confusionMatrix(nNPredictions,testing_norm$Class)

ty$table
```

to try to stop R from printing messages and warnings.

But this is what I get in my final pdf document:

```
weights:  67
initial  value 721.992732 
iter  10 value 519.008521
iter  20 value 488.124903
iter  30 value 456.941810
iter  40 value 330.558805
iter  50 value 259.373044
```

It's about 500 pages of calculations!

How can I solve this??

I have to delete all those calculations from my final document.

Can anyone help please??

I forgot to mention that I have excluded `verboseIter=T` from my rg_Control. 
But it still doesn't work.

I don't know what to do!

For the sake of completeness this is my reg_COntrol

```
Tabella_per_previsioni$Class=factor(Tabella_per_previsioni$Class,                                               labels=c("Alterato","Ottimale","Pericolo"))

set.seed(32343)

reg_Control = trainControl("repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats=5, classProbs =T) 


inTrain = createDataPartition(y=Tabella_per_previsioni$Class,p=0.75, list=FALSE)

training = Tabella_per_previsioni[inTrain,]

testing = Tabella_per_previsioni[-inTrain,]

train_stats <- preProcess(training, method="range")

training_norm <- predict(train_stats, training)

testing_norm <- predict(train_stats, testing)
```

Forgot to mention I'm using Caret.

Comment: could you put a reproducible example so that we can test things and have a better understanding of your problem?

Comment: Hi @bretauv, first of all thanks for your answer! I have edited my question so you can have a better understanding of the problem. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for editing but what I mean by a reproducible example is the code for the whole markdown (not your whole document but just a code that we can put in R Studio and that runs fine), including the YAML for example. Not sure if it's clear, tell me

Comment: Sorry @bretauv but I don't understand! :-(

Comment: If I copy the code you put in your question, it will not work because a R markdown document needs some obligatory parts in order to work well. If you create a new markdown document, there will be some code created automatically that aims to define the output (pdf, html...) and other settings. I would like you to add this code to the one you already put, so that when I copy it, it runs perfectly without any modification needed. Do you understand ? ;-)

Comment: Thanks @bretauv I understand now! Does this work for you now??(I have edited my question again)

Comment: As it is mentioned in this other question, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810476/suppress-console-output-in-r-markdown-but-keep-plot?rq=1] I have tried wrapping my object in the invisible function. But it still doesn't work! I have tried wrapping my train function..

Comment: Sometimes wrapping the code that prints to the console in a `a <- capture.output({neuralNetwork <- train(...)})` helps

Comment: Thanks @David, I will try with this solution.

Comment: could you add the packages you're using ?

Comment: I'm using Caret! @bretauv

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted everything out with David's suggestion.

"Sometimes wrapping the code that prints to the console in a

`a <- capture.output({neuralNetwork <- train(...)})`

helps".