# rmarkdown/purrr: remove list indices between plots

Tags: r, r-markdown, purrr

When I knit a document containing multiple plots obtained through purrr:map function, I get text slides in between each plot slide containing unwanted list index information (see image slides 2, 4, and 6).  I'd like to remove these and just have plots.

- I've tried `results = "hide"` and `results = FALSE` in the header.
  These just return one plot instead of many, AND the text is still
  there.
- I've tried adding invisible() around my code as recommended
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810476/suppress-console-output-in-r-markdown-but-keep-plot). I don't see a difference.

How can I remove these and just have three slides with the three plots with no text?

[image: powerpoint tray showing alternating plot and text slides]

````
---
title: "Reprex"
output: powerpoint_presentation
---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r echo=FALSE, results = FALSE}
ys <- c("mpg","cyl","disp")
ys %>% map(function(y) 
    invisible(ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp)) + geom_point(aes_string(y=y))))
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

1. To suppress the console output use `purrr::walk` instead of `map`. See e.g. https://chrisbeeley.net/?p=1198
2. To get each plot printed on a separate slide use `results='asis'` and add two newlines via `cat('\n\n')` after each plot.

````
    ---
    title: "Reprex"
    output: powerpoint_presentation
    ---
    
    ```{r include=FALSE}
    library(tidyverse)
    ```
    
    ```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
    ys <- c("mpg","cyl","disp")
    walk(ys, function(y) {
      p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp)) + geom_point(aes_string(y=y))
      print(p)
      cat('\n\n')
    })
    ```
````

[image]